# (for) part/most/all of next year

Tags: prepositions

(1) I will be free (for) part of next year.

(2) I will be free (for) most of next year.

(3) I will be free (for) all of next year.

Which one is grammatical: with or without for?

Answer (score 1):

All 3 statements are grammatically correct **if "for" is used**. "for" is a preposition that is used to show a length of time.

From [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/for_1):

> 15. used to show a length of time
>
> I'm going away **for a few days**.
>   That's all the news there is **for now**.

Answer (score 1):

@Panda is correct but all of the sentences are also grammatical if you omit the *for*. You could also substitute *during* for *for*. Whichever word you choose (*for*, *during*, no preposition at all), the meaning will be understood.